# How to compare two snaps of schema data in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables:

Current_Ranking:

```
id   rank
1     20
2     25
3     26
4     17
```

Previous_Ranking

```
id rank
1   20
2   26
3   18
4   17
5   5
```

I want to get as a result all records in Previous_Ranking that don't appear in 
Current_Ranking  (means new id)  and all records that their rank in Previous_Ranking is not the same as Current_Ranking

So expected result is:

```
id rank
2   26
3   18
5   5
```

How can I do that?
I know I can do:

```sql
    SELECT   p.id, p.rank
    FROM     Previous_Ranking p
       LEFT JOIN Current_Ranking c USING (id)
    WHERE    c.id IS NULL
```

This should give me all the new rows. But How I continue from here?

I'm using BigQuery so this can be done with native SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a left join with two criteria:

```
SELECT p.id, p.rank
FROM Previous_Ranking p
LEFT JOIN Current_Ranking c
    ON p.id = c.id
WHERE
    c.id IS NULL OR p.rank <> c.rank;
```

[image]

Note: `RANK` is a reserved keyword in many versions of SQL (though apparently not in BigQuery).  So, you might want to avoid using `RANK` as a name for columns and tables.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply do:

```
select p.id, p.rank
from Previous_Ranking p
left join Current_Ranking c 
   ON p.id = c.id
where p.c is null
   OR p.rank !=  c.rank
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `EXCEPT`:

```
select pr.*
from previous_ranking
except distinct
select r.*
from ranking;
```

Or `not exists`:

```
select pr.*
from previous_ranking pr
where not exists (select 1
                  from ranking r
                  where r.id = pr.id and r.rank = pr.rank
                 );
```

I find both of these clearer than a `left join` version.